# js beautifier - force line breaks or preserver sections of code - css

Tags: css, sublime-text-plugin, js-beautify

I'm using the "CodeFormatter" plugin for Sublime (build 4126) which uses "js-beautify"

I can use "selector_separator_newline": false or true to either have a row or column of code but because "wrap_line_length" only works with js I don't know how to break the code into more readable chunks.

Alternatively, is there a way to ignore a section of code?
The documentation gives two options (/* beautify ignore:start */ as well as /* beautify preserve:start */) but neither work with css

input:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

output option 1: ("selector_separator_newline": false)

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

output option 2: ("selector_separator_newline": true)

```
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```